# What's a opened solder bridge signifies?

Tags: stm32, soldering

I'm new to STM32. Recently I'm trying to understand the schematic of it. I came across the term "soldering bridge" default: open. Does it signifies that the two pins are opened (which means not connected) or it means two of the pins are shorted?[image]

Comment: 1st time I have seen solder bridge used as a feature with Ref. Des. "SB" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator

Comment: Think about the connections.  You can power up/down whatever is connected or hardwire it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means they are normally not connected.  You can place a blob of solder across it to connect if needed.

Comment: But it's a good idea to look at the board and check.  That's the sort of thing that is most likely to not match the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have performed connectivity on those bridges using my multi-meter and then verify that SB open signifies those bridges are not connected.

Answer (score 4):

It's two adjacent pads intended to be bridged with solder to connect them depending on the board configuration. It's just like a jumper with header pins and a shunt but is cheaper and more permanent.

Open is not connected. Closed switch is connected. In electronics, we use the analogy of a switch, not a door or floodgate (which is opposite).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest it means "Not connected". Thus pin 4 on the P-channel MOSFET Gate has to be taken low to pass along U5V from Source to Drain.